# gtsummary and gtsave to .docx generate corrupt column labels

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

Trying some effective ways to generate publication-ready tables for a MS Word document.

I successfully generated a summary table with tbl_summary {gtsummary}. However, when trying to gtsave() the table the output column labels are quite corrupted.

Here is a reprex (hopefully)

```
#data
test1 <- data.frame(
              Country = c("Italy","Italy","Italy",
                          "Netherlands","Netherlands","Netherlands"),
    Duration = c(47L, 28L, 23L, 37L, 16L, 29L),
   Frequency = c(0.87, 1.11, 3.17, 2.08, 1, 1.03)
         )

#table
tab1 <- test1 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by =  Country,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(all_continuous() ~ 1, all_categorical()~ 0) 
  ) %>% add_overall() 

#Saving table
as_gt(tab1) %>% gtsave("Output/Tables/tab1.docx") #first line is broken though
```

[image: The output .docx file is this]

I tried to compile and save a table with just gt() and gtsave() and the problem does not appear. I hypothesize this may be due to gtsummary.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of gt for the moment. Should be resolved soon.
https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me quickly!

Comment: Any news about this? On the link above it says word is supported now, but I am still encountering troubles.

Comment: it is now supported. make sure you have the most up to date gtsummary and gt

Comment: Thanks, after updating the packages, gtsave() works for .rtf but fails for .docx. It gives the following error:  Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  StartTag: invalid element name [68]                             Also, partially related, please see the comment I sent you on another issues here https://gist.github.com/ddsjoberg/a55afa74ac58e1f895862fcabab62406#file-multinom_pivot_wider-r

Comment: I saw that comment, but no time to answer every post unfortunately. Regarding your docx rendering issues I suggest you make a separate stack overflow post with reprex